# How change memoir header chapter element to omit "Chapter"

Tags: header-footer, memoir

With `memoir`, how do I change the following source so that
the word "Chapter does not appear in the header on even-numbered pages?

That is, where I now get

```
Chapter 1. The Fall of Humpty-Dumpty
```

I will get instead:

```
1. The Fall of Humpty-Dumpty
```

Source:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{textcase}

\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}
\makeoddfoot{chapter}{}{\sffamily\thepage}{}

\makeheadrule {headings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}

\nouppercaseheads

\newcommand{\mainheads}{%
  \makeevenhead{headings}{\bfseries\sffamily\thepage}{}{\bfseries\sffamily \leftmark}%
  \makeoddhead{headings}{\bfseries\sffamily\rightmark}{}{\bfseries\sffamily\thepage}%
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\mainheads

\chapter{The Fall of \NoCaseChange{Humpty-Dumpty}}

\section{The Wall}

\lipsum[1-15]

\section{The \NoCaseChange{King's} horses}

\end{document}
```

Here's what I have now for even-numbered headers:

[image: Unwanted Chapter in even-numbered page headers]

Note that the odd-numbered headers already omit "Section", as desired:

[image: Even-numbered page headers OK]

Comment: You need to run `\pagestyle{headings} ` after you issue `\nouppercaseheads ` otherwise it does nothing. To remove the prefix look up `\addtopsmarks` and use its last of three arguments to redefine what chapter sends to the header

Comment: Erh you set the header with `\MakeUppercase` and complain why `\nouppercaseheads` does not work? What exactly did you expect? Please update your question and explain what exactly it is you want to do.

Comment: Remocing the chapter prefix can be done via `\addtopsmarks{headings}{}{
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
}
\pagestyle{headings}`

Comment: @daleif: I do not have any pagestyle named `headings` here; the pagestyle is `chapter`.

Comment: @daleif: Oops, that `\MakeUppercase` was left over from a different attempt where I had meant to try `MakeTextLowercase`. I'm editing my question to fix that

Comment: the chapter pagestyle only affects the first page of a chapter, it does not affact the other pages, since you are not specifying any other pagestyles the active over all page style is the default: `headings`

Comment: You have a typo on the line right after `\nouppercaseheads` and if you add the line I suggested in a comment above you get what you wanted.

Comment: @daleif: The repeated line was an artifact of the way I copied and pasted my source file in pieces into the SE editor. Sorry; source shown in question is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
\addtopsmarks{headings}{}{ 
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{}{. \ } 
} 
\pagestyle{headings}
```

Remember the last line to have the changes merged into the page styles currently in use

Comment: Where, exactly should the `\pagestyle{headings}`, which is for main matter,  go in the source? In my actual, book-length document, I will be changing the headings style for front matter, main matter, and back matter.

Comment: @murray you could add it to your mainheads, but I don't really see any need to have three different pagestyles, that just looks odd

Comment: In fact, the index will have different headers; the preface, table of contents, bibiliography, and other backmatter will have a different kind of header (same head rule as main page style and same position of page number, but just the word "Preface", "Contents", "Bibliography", etc., at the right of verso and at the left of recto).

Comment: @murray you don't need special pagestyles for that, done right it will be added to the headers automatically